# Is there any API function to get the matched train phrase for a user query in Dialogflow?

Tags: python, api, dialogflow-es

I'm building a chatbot and for some testing and benchmarking purposes, I need the matched train phrase and intent for a user query. For example, consider a restaurant booking intent with train phrases:
 
1. Book a table a 5pm
 
2. Reserve a table at 5pm

Now when a user query is 'I need reservation at 5pm' I need to know which train phrase the user query matched, and hence the intent. In this case, I'd expect the query to match with the second training phrase.
 
 
However, I'm unable to find any API functions in the dialogflow documentation to achieve this. Is there any way I could possibly do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. 
 
Thank you.

Comment: Since they both have the same meaning, I do not understand why you need to separate them. You should also consider that users can ask for the same thing in different way (for example "I want to make reservation. Book a table at 5 pm"). In any case, you can create two different intent and fill the training data emphasizing on the words "book" and "reserve". Or, if having those words is super important you can make them required, and control it from code behind.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and apologies for not giving a good example. As you pointed out, there can be a lot of variations for a query and typically there'd be 10-15 training phrases for each intent. The purpose is to check which training phrase among all these does Dialogfow match the user query with before it returns the parameters(slots). As I mentioned it is required for certain testing and benchmarking purposes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's not known what algorithms DF uses behind the scene but in any case that's not how neural network works. The training phrases are used to train the model and there won't  be 1:1 matching.